# How can I determine what packages I had installed before a new install?

Tags: 64-bit, package-management, 32-bit

#### Situation:

- want to move from 32-bit to 64-bit environment (taking advantage of >4GB RAM)
- bought new HDD and installed new OS
- mounted old HDD as a secondary device

#### Question:

- How can I determine all package I had installed (irrespective of platform - I'll install proper platform on the new install)?

Comment: related [question about services](http://askubuntu.com/q/293104/3544)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method to automate the new installation and have it install anything you had on your old system would be:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

Back that file up and after installation do...

```
dpkg --get-selections < installed-software
dselect
```

If needed you can edit the text file and remove, alter the name of, or include packages.

---

> Noteworthy

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

shows a list of what you did using apt-get.

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

will list packagas that where installed manually.