# How can I determine what services I had running before a new install?

Tags: services

#### Background:

- want to move from 32-bit to 64-bit environment (taking advantage of >4GB RAM)
- bought new HDD and installed new OS
- mounted old HDD as a secondary device

#### Question:

- How can I determine all services I had installed and running on the old system?

Comment: this is related to my previous [question about packages](http://askubuntu.com/q/293100/3544)

Comment: the question shown as a duplicate ([How do you get a list of all starting services?](http://askubuntu.com/q/57909/3544)) is interesting - but not at all a duplicate. That question does not deal with how to find what *were* the services running before a new install (as this question clearly indicates). That question is about what services *are* running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chroot` command on your partition on which you had old OS. Once you're done with `chroot`, do anything you want like you are using your old OS again.
you can see list of installed packages or you can see the content of `/etc/init.d` to see list of services.

To do `chroot` you can can see up to 6th step in http://alok.fossguru.in/content/rescuing-system-chroot

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
service --status-all
```

or:

```
ls /etc/init.d
```

Comment: the `service` command won't work - that will show me what is running *now* ... not what *was* running :)

Answer (score 0):

you can list all the service  with `sudo initctl list | sort`. Give your password after typing the command.

hope that helps.

Comment: if I had not already installed the new OS, yes - but without `chroot`, I don't think this would work